# Empty images from iPhone app package contents, how to encode?

Tags: iphone, image, package, ipa

i have a simple iPhone app (*.ipa), which downloaded from AppStore.
I have changed extension from ipa to zip, open an archive and move to 'Show package contents'.
In this folder i have an images, but all of it not displayed, looks like its empty.

Can somebody give advice? how to encode images from this opened apps to viewable?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run **[appcrush](https://github.com/boctor/idev-recipes/tree/master/Utilities/appcrush)** on it! A ruby script.

Read: https://github.com/boctor/idev-recipes/tree/master/Utilities/appcrush

Good Luck!